# Reset GeoServer admin password or create admin

Tags: geoserver, password

I try to get access to a GeoServer installation and forgot the password for it. I have root access to the host. Here is some server information:

```
GeoServer Version
2.21.0
Git Version
6dcc807326ddc0eb9ad2f9a2e700967bf1ac5d9a
Build-Datum
22-May-2022 09:42
GeoTools Version
27.0 (rev 8fe62b2b2d7b585a116d18d3217ed5c441f4a1ad)
GeoWebCache Version
1.21.0 (rev 1.21.x/f53b7f0a4a56d99bebe0af69ca58caf7a221d347)
```

Solutions I already tried and didn't work for me:

[GeoServer - change Master Password - masterpw.info missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107265/geoserver-change-master-password-masterpw-info-missing) ## I changed all the files mentioned in the post, restarted the server but can not login with the data set in the XML-Files

https://geoserver-users.narkive.com/rDV1AUhb/forgot-the-geoserver-login-password ## Same as Above

[Changing geoserver admin password](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122621/changing-geoserver-admin-password) ## Because I cannot log in to the web interface, I cannot change the password there.

Does anyone have an idea how I could gain access to the server again?